# how to extract columns for dictionary that do not have keys

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

so I have tried resources of how transform dict in data frame, but the problem this is an weird Dict.

it is not like `key: {} , key: {} and etc..`

the data has lots of items. But the goal is extract only the stuff inside of dict {}, if possible the dates also is a plus.

data:

```
id,client,source,status,request,response,queued,created_at,updated_at
54252,sdf,https://asdasdadadad,,"{
    "year": "2010",
    "casa": "aca",
    "status": "p",
    "Group": "57981",
}",,1,"2020-05-02 11:06:17","2020-05-02 11:06:17"
54252,msc-lp,https://discover,,"{
    "year": "27",
    "casa": "Na",
    "status": "p",
    "Group": "57981",
}"
```

my attempts:

```
#attempt 1
with open('data.csv') as fd:
    pairs = (line.split(None) for line in fd)
    res   = {int(pair[0]):pair[1] for pair in pairs if len(pair) == 2 and pair[0].isdigit()}



#attempt 2
import json

# reading the JSON data using json.load()
file = 'data.json'
with open(file) as train_file:
    dict_train = json.load(train_file)

# converting json dataset from dictionary to dataframe
train = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_train, orient='index')
train.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)


#attempt 3
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df.melt(id_vars=["index", "Date"], var_name="variables",value_name="values")
```

Nothening works due the data be weird shaped

Expected output:
All the items inside of the dictionary, every key will be one column at df

```
Date                     year  casa  status    Group
2020-05-02 11:06:17     2010   aca    p       57981
2020-05-02 11:06:17      27     Na    p       57981
```

Comment: you need to parse the last column as json

Comment: how to I access only the last column, like my loop will run it all @Aqua 4

Comment: your csv is ill-formatted it should be only 2 rows, but due to json object you have "\n" as well. while creating could you just remove "\n" for that json and get it in a single line?

Comment: Im sorry, I do not understand, what is "\n" ?

Answer (score 1):

Format data into a valid csv stucture:

```
id,client,source,status,request,response,queued,created_at,updated_at
54252,sdf,https://asdasdadadad,,'{ "ag": "2010", "ca": "aca", "ve": "p", "Group": "57981" }',,1,"2020-05-02 11:06:17","2020-05-02 11:06:17"
54252,msc-lp,https://discover,,'{ "ag": "27", "ca": "Na", "ve": "p", "Group": "57981" }',,1,"2020-05-02 11:06:17","2020-05-02 11:06:17"
```

This should work for the worst-case scenario as well,
check it out.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

def parse_column(data):
    try:
        return json.loads(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None



df =pd.read_csv('tmp.csv',converters={"request":parse_column}, quotechar="'")
```

Comment: I updated the question, with desired output. Thank you for helping @Aqua 4, so it is giving an output like: ```Columns = id,client,source,status,request,response,queued,created_at,updated_at ```  being all values under the column ```id``` like ```row1:  "ag":"2010"  row2:  "ca":"aca"```

Comment: you will have to fix your json and csv structure, this way you can easily parse csv